# Iterate inside a multilevel object in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this json returned from an ajax call:

```
{"datasets":[
    {"data":[0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,2], "service_ID": 1},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], "service_ID": 2},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], "service_ID": 3},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4], "service_ID": 4},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], "service_ID": 5}
   ]
}
```

Every element inside `data` object is a value for a month, from January to December (an array of 12 elements)

I need to loop inside `datasets` to get every value inside `data` object and get the sum, in this example: `2+1+5+2+1+3+2+4+1 = 21`

I've tried

```
var total = 0;

          $.each(datasets, function(index, data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, month) {
                    $.each(month, function(index, value) {
                        total = total + value;
                    });
                });
          });
```

but i get `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a` error.

What's the best way to get what i need?

Comment: Use `console.log()` (or set breakpoints) to see what you are working with inside each of the  `$.each` loops. Will realize the third loop is not needed and that you are visualizing it incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick explanation of `reduce`. It's name is the clue here as it basically takes a series of separate values (an array) and reduces them down to a single value. And getting the of sum of integers in an array is actually a very good example of that.

`reduce` accepts a callback that accepts two arguments - the first is the accumulator, the value to which all the other values are added, and the second is the current value in the iteration. Here we also set the initial value of the accumulator as 0.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const out = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
console.log(out); // 10
```

In gurvinder's answer (I've changed the variable names to make it a little easier to understand) all that is happening is a couple of sum operations taking place. In short we iterate over the datasets array with `reduce` and grab the sum of the integers in each data array (with `reduce` again), and add each of those `arrSum`s to the main accumulator, `sum`.

```
obj.datasets.reduce((sum, obj) => {
   return sum + obj.data.reduce((arrSum, int) => arrSum + int , 0);
}, 0);
```

But there's more!

Here's a simple function that returns the sum of two numbers:

```js
const sum = (x, y) => x + y;
console.log(sum(1, 2)); // 3
```

Now, because JavaScript is a functional language (functions are first-class objects) we can use that function to separate out the sum functionality of the `reducer`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const sum = (acc, curr) => acc + curr;
const out = arr.reduce(sum, 0);
console.log(out);
```

This helps us write more functional code, and, generally, allow for better code reuse.

For example, here's a rewrite of gurvinders code:

```
const sum = (sum, value) => sum + value;

const out = data.datasets.reduce((total, obj) => { 
  return sum(total, obj.data.reduce(sum), 0);
}, 0);
```

Hope this was a useful introduction to `reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `reduce`

```
obj.datasets.reduce( function( a, b ){  //
   return a + b.data.reduce( (c, d) => c + d , 0); // 0 is the accumulator for data property of each item in the array 
} , 0); //0 is the accumulator which is the final output
```

or even shorter

```
obj.datasets.reduce( ( a, b ) => a + b.data.reduce( ( c, d ) => c + d , 0)  , 0 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {"datasets":[
    {"data":[0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,2], "service_ID": 1},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], "service_ID": 2},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], "service_ID": 3},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4], "service_ID": 4},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], "service_ID": 5}
   ]
};

var output = obj.datasets.reduce( function( a, b ){ 
   return a + b.data.reduce( (c, d) => c + d , 0);
} , 0);

console.log( output );
```

Comment: You should also add what's wrong with OP's implementation

Comment: @Satpal sure, will do

Comment: And now to explain the magic of this code so the OP, and future visitors, can learn. Upvoted though, because that is a little bit beautiful...

Comment: Very nice script but i can't understand how reduce works. But very good!

Comment: @Satpal I am unable to replicate `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a error.` from the OP's code. Were you able to do so?

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini, I've added an answer that explains `reduce` a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```js
var dataset = {"datasets":[
    {"data":[0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,2], "service_ID": 1},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], "service_ID": 2},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], "service_ID": 3},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4], "service_ID": 4},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], "service_ID": 5}
   ]
}

var total = 0;

$.each(dataset['datasets'], function(index1, data) {
  $.each(data['data'], function(index2, value) {

    total = total + value;

  });
});

console.log(total)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var example = {"datasets":[
    {"data":[0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,2], "service_ID": 1},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], "service_ID": 2},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], "service_ID": 3},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4], "service_ID": 4},
    {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], "service_ID": 5}
   ]
}

var sum = 0;
example.datasets.forEach(set => {
    set.data.forEach(data => {
        sum += data;        
  })
})
console.log(sum) // 21
```